# Is it possible to create own result / library in phonegap barcode scanner?

Tags: cordova, barcode

I'm working with jquery mobile to develop mobile apps, and use phonegap build to publish them.
I could not find any plugins to use the device´s camera to scan barcodes...

I'm now going to try "phonegap" and I know that there is a barcode scanner plugin in the framework. I just want to be sure whether or not it is possible to create my own library/result when I, for example, scan a chips barcode? It could for example result "This chips is good"

Any ideas out there?

Comment: You can create anything if you [put your mind to it](https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner/blob/9270025f71891b2f46a38b7bc3d1223b4955dce2/README.md)

Comment: Okay, but where can i store all the products?

Comment: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/261 - barcode scanner for phonegap build

Comment: In one of the multitude of [storage options](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

Comment: any code examples or demos ?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon : I can see, but the most important thing for me is, I want to decide the results when someone scans a product

Answer (score 0):

sure you can. you need to register your Scandit barcode scanner first before add into your project.

http://www.scandit.com/

https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin